# Графика в C#. Работа с PictureBox

Tags: графика

с#. Закрасить эллипсы последовательными секторами. 
Если сделать эллипс областью отсечения. До цикла сделать 1 сектор. Затем в цикле с помощью setClip(path,combineMode.Union ) добавлять последующие секторы. Почему не получается добавить даже один сектор к исходному?

```
path2.AddArc(rect, 0, 30);
path2.AddLine(0, 0, x / 2, 0);
g.DrawPath(pen, path2);

GraphicsPath path3 = new GraphicsPath();
GraphicsPath path4 = new GraphicsPath();                     
path3.AddArc(rect, 30, 60);
g.SetClip(path3, CombineMode.Union);
path4.AddLine(0, 0, 0, y / 2);
g.SetClip(path4, CombineMode.Union);
g.FillPath(brush, path4);
```

Comment: Какой фреймворк-то? WPF? WinForms? (Кажется, WinForms, исходя из `g.`).

Comment: Windows Forms. Даже если не через AddArc, а через AddPie делать, то все равно не выходит